# How to automate installing ruby and setting it as the global system version?

Tags: ruby

Installing ruby is easy enough using apt-get install ruby1.9.1.

But how can I set it as the default/system/global ruby in a automated fashion?

Answer (score 0):

Simply make sure that the ruby found in $PATH is (a link to) the right one.

On my Ubuntu 12.04 (if I disable rvm, which I'm normally using to manage rubies),

```
which ruby
```

shows */usr/bin/ruby* and *ls -l `which ruby`*  reveals that it's a link to 
*/etc/alternatives/ruby* which is again a link, whose destination is intended to be managed by the **update-alternatives** command.

So I can either use **update-alternatives** to point it to the right version (probably the preferred way to do it), create the link manually, or make sure the $PATH variable ends up at a different link (perhaps one placed in  $HOME/bin ) that points to the right ruby. 
(Note: the actually binaries on my system are installed in /usr/bin and are distinguished by having their version in their name, e.g. /usr/bin/ruby1.9.3).

All of these instructions are bash commands (or references to bash commands) so automation should be just about putting those commands in a script.

Comment: I'm on a fresh install of Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS, and me doing which ruby returns nothing, `The program 'ruby' can be found in the following packages:
 * ruby1.8
 * ruby1.9.1
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>`  So I'm looking a way to automate this in a script somehow.

Comment: Try making a link to it. ruby1.9.1 should work so all you need to do is make an alias or link named ruby that will run ruby1.9.1, which is by default in /usr/bin/.

Comment: You can do it with sudo ln -s /usr/bin/ruby{1.9.1,}; sudo ln -s /usr/bin/irb{1.9.1,}.